# Comparison function in Python using Lambdas

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I am trying to understand lambdas and I get the idea but how do I define multiple conditions for a Point2 [x,y] comparison, so something like:

```
if x1 < x2: -1
if x1 == x2: 0
if x1 > x2: 1
```

Comment: -1: spending time "understanding" lambdas.  They're "def" spelled funny.

Answer (score 6):

The code above is equivalent to:

```
cmp(x1,x2)
```

or in a (ugly) lambda expression:

```
lambda x1,x2: 1 if x1>x2 else (0 if x1==x2 else -1)
```

(works only in Python 2.6 and above).

Normally you should use lambda expressions only for functions like

```
def fun(...):
    return ...
```

Comment: When you say:

if x1>x2

what does it return? It just goes to else?

Comment: 1 if x1>x2 else (0 if x1==x2 else -1) is the python equivalent of Javas: x1>x2?1:(x1==x2?0:-1). And yes it tries x1>x2 if that is False, it takes the value after else, if True it takes the value before the it (1 in that case)

Comment: From PEP 308, it looks like it will work in Python 2.5 if you put brackets in: "lambda x1,x2: (1 if x1>x2 else (0 if x1==x2 else -1))" - but I can't easily test that.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Updated to be real Python according to [PEP308](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) :) Note that the PEP has interesting information about how this should be parenthesized depending on which version of Python you're using. I won't attempt to reproduce it here - just read the PEP!

How about:

```
-1 if x1 < x2 else (0 if x1 == x2 else 1)
```

(That's without any knowledge of Python lambda expressions, but it's a fairly common way of expressing this logic in a single expression, which I guess is what you're after.)

EDIT: Others have suggested using `cmp` - I've been assuming that the questioner actually wants more complicated logic, such as providing their own comparisons, but wants the general form of "choose from a few conditions in a single expression".

Comment: Thanks Jon. I was surprised to see you reply to a python question but knew you would have great lambda knowledge from C# :)

Comment: Doh - looked at a Python page, but it was giving an example from PHP. Aargh. Trying to do too many things at once.

Answer (score 4):

```
my_compare = lambda x1,x2 : cmp(x1, x2)
my_compare( -100, 100 )
```

Comment: my_compare = cmp; my_compare(-100, 100)

Comment: Better yet, just: cmp(-100, 100) Code was purely to demonstrate lamda usage.

Answer (score 4):

In such a case, lambda expressions aren't usually the best thing. As Jon Skeet mentioned, you're gonna end with multiple if-else expressions:

```
lambda x1, x2: -1 if x1 < x2 else (0 if x1 == x2 else -1)
```

For your specific problem:

```
lambda x1, x2: cmp(x1, x2)
```

is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Simply one line of code to return the biggest of two values:

```
greater = lambda x,y : x if (x>y) else y   
print(greater(3,5))
```

Comment: ...and what about if they are equals?

Comment: then the equal element will get returned , which is intutive I guess